# Is 5 hours and 45 minutes enough for an international-domestic connection at Auckland airport?

Tags: transit, short-connections, akl

I have a question regarding layover time in Auckland airport. So, I bought a ticket from Qatar Airways from Tehran to Wellington via Doha, Adelaide and Auckland.

I've read from this forum that a 1 hour layover in Doha (if not taking luggage) would be enough. Is this still the case?

Also, regarding Auckland, since it's an international flight do we need to take our luggage for screening upon entry or will Qatar give it to us at the destination? I bought the tickets from Qatar but the last flight is operated by Jetstar so I am not sure what will I do? Anyhow, is 5 hours 45 minutes enough?

[image]

Comment: I have travelled today, 1 hour is enough if your first flight isn't delayed

Comment: Let me turn this upside down: is there _any airport_ where 5:45 is _not_ enough? How would that airport stay in business if it took _six hours_ to get from one plane to another??

Comment: @chx: I'd be pretty shocked but... maybe you go through customs, leave the secured area, take a bus or train to a different airport, enter the (new) secured area, go through customs again, and also all of the above have huge delays because of... I dunno, protests or something?

Comment: 5:45 is plenty even for JFK-EWR (4:30 is recommended, an hour to get out, two hours to get across although it shouldn't take more than 1:40 and 1:30 to get in) which is one of the worst for two airport transfers and the trains for that are rarely if ever interrupted by protests but also no one accounts for protests in deciding whether to buy a ticket, that's force majeure. Might as well decide to not fly because there might be an earthquake at the airport you transition at...

Answer (score 9):

That is more than enough.

No connection is ever guaranteed, but unless something highly unusual happens, you will have a lot of leisure time in the airport.

Answer (score 4):

Much more than enough time, I suggest you get a coffee or tea and enjoy the short walk from the international terminal to the domestic one instead of taking the bus (though that walk may be closed for construction still, I'm not sure). Sunrise isn't til 7:30 so maybe wait for a bit before leaving the international terminal so you can see that.

You will have to pick up your luggage from the carousel for screening (remember, [don't bring any fresh fruit/vegetables](https://www.mpi.govt.nz/bring-send-to-nz/bringing-and-posting-items-to-nz/how-to-declare-items-when-arriving-in-nz/) or meat, dirt, plants, wood, basically anything you can imagine which might harbour insects, and if you have anything you're not sure about declare it to be safe or you can get a big fine) and take it to the domestic terminal. They'll tell you which carousel your flight's luggage is on, you can also usually just follow other people from your flight if you're not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely plenty, my routine timings from aircraft door opening to kerbside at the international terminal is about 45 minutes for a full A380s worth of passengers - that includes going through extended customs (with something to declare) and immigration.

Then you turn right and walk the length of the international terminal, across a road and on to the domestic terminal.  Probably another 20 minutes.

If your baggage is checked through to Wellington, the above will be even easier.